# Flask Sqlalchemy sometimes rolls back after commit

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table `Orders` in which i have a `comments` field which is a json array of json objects
like

```json
[
   {"timestamp":"timestamp_value","message":"message_value"}
]
```

Here is a flask endpoint function i am using to add a comment

```py
class CommentOnOrderService:
    """
    Contains the function that will allow commenting and correcting any records in the order table
    """

    def comment_on_order(self, params):
        engine = db.get_engine()
        econ = engine.connect()
        session = Session(bind=econ)
        conn = session.connection()

        order_number = params.get("order_number", "")
        timestamp = params.get("timestamp", "")
        if timestamp:
            timestamp = datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp)
        status = params.get("status", "")
        comments = params.get("comments", "")
        comment_to = params.get("comment_to", "")
        comment_from = params.get("comment_from", "")
        truncate = params.get("truncate", "") == "true"
        
        try:
            row: OrderStatus
            if timestamp:
                row = session.query(OrderStatus).filter(
                    and_(
                        OrderStatus.order_number == order_number,
                        OrderStatus.timestamp == timestamp,
                    )
                ).first()
            else:
                row = (
                    session.query(OrderStatus).filter(OrderStatus.order_number == order_number)
                    .order_by(desc("timestamp"))
                    .first()
                )
            
            if not row:
                raise Exception("No record found")
                
            if status:
                row.status = status

            if comments:
                if truncate:
                    row.comments = [
                        {
                            "timestamp": datetime.now().isoformat(),
                            "comment_to": comment_to,
                            "comment_from": comment_from,
                            "comment_body": comments,
                        }
                    ]
                else:
                    prevdata = row.comments
                    row.comments = prevdata + [
                        {
                            "timestamp": datetime.now().isoformat(),
                            "comment_to": comment_to,
                            "comment_from": comment_from,
                            "comment_body": comments,
                        }
                    ]
            elif truncate:
                row.comments = []

            with session.begin_nested():
                session.add(row)

            session.commit()
            econ.execute("COMMIT")
             
            return Resp.success(
                {"message": "Commented on order successfully", "params": params}
            )

        except Exception as exception:
            return Resp.error([str(exception)])
        finally:
            session.close()
```

Most of the times, the comment gets added, and it reflects properly in the ui im building aswell.
However, sometimes, when it gets added, it shows in the ui, then randomly gets rolled back.

I tried using `mutable_dict`, and some other methods, but to no avail i can decipher why it rolls back. Could someone please help me decipher this?

Comment: Why are you committing twice? `session.commit()` will emit a COMMIT statement to the database already, then you're calling `econ.execute("COMMIT")`, that means, sending another commit by your engine object. You should only use the engine to instantiate your session. Maybe they are conflicting.

Comment: i added it twice thinking maybe the first commit had failed. the issue happens even if i  add the commit statement once or none at all (thinking that the session.close() will handle it)

Comment: Are you actually seeing a ROLLBACK being issued in the server or SQLAlchemy logs?

Comment: yes, i am seeing ROLLBACK explicitly being done in the sqlalchemy output

Comment: I have noticed why this ROLLBACK was happening. 
I have another service that continuously polls the tables. this was causing a problem in Acquiring the lock for that row while updating, this caused a race condition and hence the rollbacks were happening. Hence using with_update_for function provided by sqlalchemy solved the issue